# Labels are overlapping with autolayout?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, label

I have constraints placed on my two labels. Both have leading constraints, the top one has a vertical space to safe space constraint and then the bottom has a top space to the top label. Both my tableView and TableCell have the adequate row height and the connections have been deleted and reconnected in an effort to fix the issue. The problem still persists. What could this be?

[image]

Update: Odd Behavior...
Still playing around with this and I've managed to learn that the top label is not the issue. When I add constraints to the bottom label, regardless of leading/top/bottom, it overlaps the top label. If I remove them, as shown in the photo, the label is fine and stays in place. I've never encountered this before so clueless as to how to explain it.

[image]

Comment: That looks wierd... Can you add a screenshot of the view hierarchy / layout inspector? Also, how is the cell height calculated?

Comment: Are you sure this prototype cell is the one being used? Did you set the identifier? Also, are you adding or removing any view programmatically?

Comment: Do you have constraints between the cells ? It looks like there is no horizontal spacing between the 2 cells

Comment: The TableCell class and identifier are correct - copied over to be safe. No views are being added or removed. As for the third question, this is one cell with two labels inside.

Comment: Give bottom constraint to the second label.

Comment: I've tried that. I'll add an update.

Comment: I was having this problem, and it went away when I stopped using the default prototype cell and dragged out another UITableViewCell from the library and set it up.

Comment: I did the same haha. Thankfully I didn't have much of anything to add but yes, this solved my problem.